# Scanning a set or list of computers with MBSA?

Tags: windows

Looking at the interface for MBSA, I see the option to scan a domain or range of IPs, but not a list of computers. I have several computers in the lab here I want to scan, but I don't want to scan the entire domain. The IPs for them are not contiguous. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a text file containing the computer names you want to scan (1 name per line) and then run the MBSA command line program as follows:

```
mbsacli /listfile computernames.txt ...
```

where *computernames.txt* is your text file and and "..." are the other command line options you wish to use.

There's a great reference at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302360.aspx.